# How do I keep all escape characters in a SQL string for querying a POSTGRES DB using R?

Tags: r, string, postgresql, escaping

I am using R to query data from a Postgres database.  The query I created in pgAdmin3 has lots of escape characters in it, and I'd to pull in the entire SQL string without having to deal with escape characters *again*, something like Python's triple quotes """.

```
SELECT brand
,regexp_replace(upper(hybridtype), '\(.*\)|\/|-|TM|\s','','g') as hybrid
FROM seeds
```

How can I get that SQL text into R retaining all the characters?

Comment: are you on a *nix platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PGAdmin, copy the text into your clipboard.
Then in R:

```
  sql_qry <- clipPaste()
```

Where clipPaste is defined as follows:

```
clipPaste <- function(flat=TRUE) {
    con <- pipe("pbpaste", open = "rb")
    ret <- readLines(con, warn = FALSE)
    if (flat)
        ret <- paste0(ret, collapse = "\n")
    close(con)
    return(ret)
}
```

All characters will be appropriately escaped.

Comment: What is the "flat" object in the answer?  I removed that if statement, and the solution worked.  Thanks!!!

Comment: solution when reading in an SQL file:  clipPaste <- function(sqlfn) {
  ret <- readLines(sqlfn, warn = FALSE)
  ret <- paste0(ret, collapse = "\n")
  return(ret)
}

Comment: @JessieinAg -- whoops! `flat` was an argument to the function.  I've corrected the answer